# how add image to a form along with its loading bar using angular4

Tags: angular, angular4-forms

I have a form in angular 4.
and i am trying to post the form into a server.
What is the way to add images in a from using angular4 with progress bar?textboxes and dropdowns
The form is already having some 
when i am trying to load an image, it  must show progress bar when the image is loading.

Comment: can anyone suggest some links and some guidance

Comment: Have a look at prime ng file uploader. You will need to post the form as JSON though which is pretty standard now compared to posting a form.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.  and, i am trying to use <p-fileUpload> by importing "FileUpload" from a nodemodule "primeng". then, i am getting the following error... If 'p-fileUpload' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.

Comment: Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
'p-fileUpload' is not a known element:

Answer (score 1):

Use PrimeNg controls:

1. npm install primeng --save
2. import {FileUploadModule} from 'primeng/fileupload'; in your
   component or module.
3. Add below code snippet in your HTML template

```html
<p-fileUpload name="myfile[]" url="./upload.php"></p-fileUpload>
```

[PrimeNg FileUpload](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/fileupload)